# How do i convert 'google.cloud.documentai.v1beta2.types.document.Document' into JSON?

Tags: python, json, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am using Google Cloud Document AI's Form Parser API. After i do the request to the API , I get a response with type `google.cloud.documentai.v1beta2.types.document.Document`. I tried to write it to JSON using `json.dumps()`  but it gives `JSONDecodeError` because `JSON.dumps()` dont know how to serialize object of type `google.cloud.documentai.v1beta2.types.document.Document`.

I am confused how to convert this to JSON

Any Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that the `google.cloud.documentai.v1beta2.types.document.Document` object inherits from `proto.Message`, which itself inherits from `proto.MessageMeta`. You can use the `proto.MessageMeta.to_json` function to convert the Document object to a json string, like so:

```
import json
from google.cloud.documentai_v1beta3 import Document

json_string = Document.to_json(document)
dict_obj = json.loads(json_string)
with open("document.json", mode='w') as my_file:
    json.dump(dict_obj, my_file)
```

The source code for `proto.Message` was a little hard to find, so here it is: https://github.com/googleapis/proto-plus-python/blob/cfd5b6caca3fa9add89d8c69ea620505dd90dd7c/proto/message.py#L330

Comment: It seems Document AI does not enjoy the greatest documentation and this was the only place I found the answer on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

basically you have to write a function that explores the Document object, and then assemble entire JSON yourself by code.